# Where does the $kΔt$ go?

Tags: calculus, limits

Frame 142 out of Quick Calculus, 2nd Edition: Suppose the position of an object is given by $S=f(t)=kt^2+lt+S_0$, where $k$, $l$ and $S_0$ are constants.  Find $v$.

I've worked the problem to:

$$\lim\limits_{\Delta t\to 0}\big[k(2t+\Delta t)+l\big] $$

But the next step, which I do not understand, states that:

$$\lim\limits_{\Delta t\to 0}\big[k(2t+\Delta t)+l\big]  = 2kt+l$$

What happened to the $k\Delta t$?

Comment: $k\Delta t$ vanishes since $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was answered in the comments and is unlikely to be of use to others.

Comment: That's what I suspected but since the other Δt's were cancelled out algebraically it didn't make sense.  Thanks!